# Add column vector of ones to each subarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have a 3d array of zeros,

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((8,3,4))
```

And want to append a column vector of ones to each subarray:

```
from statsmodels.add_tools import add_constant
print(np.array([add_constant(i, prepend=False) for i in a])[:3])
[[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]]

 [[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]]

 [[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]]]
```

Is there a faster way to this than the above?  Not having luck with `np.apply_along_axis` although I don't suspect that would be faster anyway.  I'm thinking something like `np.insert(a, slice(...?), 1.)` may be a better alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Here's one with [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) -

```
def append_ones_concat(a):
    ones_ar = np.ones((a.shape[:-1]+(1,)),dtype=a.dtype)
    return np.concatenate((a, ones_ar), axis=-1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [189]: a = np.zeros((2,3,4))

In [190]: append_ones(a)
Out[190]: 
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]]])
```

**Approach #2**

Using `array-initialization` -

```
def append_ones_init(a):
    shp = np.array(a.shape)
    shp[-1] += 1
    out = np.ones(shp,dtype=a.dtype)
    out[...,:-1] = a
    return out
```

**Approach #3**

With `numba` for marginal improvement over `concatenate` based one on `3D` array case -

```
from numba import njit

def append_ones_numba(a):
    shp = np.array(a.shape)
    shp[-1] += 1
    out = np.empty(shp,dtype=a.dtype)
    append_ones_numba_func(a, out)
    return out

@njit
def append_ones_numba_func(a, out):
    m,n,r = out.shape
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            for k in range(r-1):
                out[i,j,k] = a[i,j,k]
            out[i,j,r-1] = 1
```

Timings -

```
In [273]: a = np.zeros((800,300,400))

In [274]: %timeit append_ones_init(a)
     ...: %timeit append_ones_concat(a)
     ...: %timeit append_ones_numba(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 136 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 113 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 105 ms per loop
```

Comment: This is cool (+1), but I think your first suggestion in the comments was better... something wrong with that?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yeah, its slower on bigger arrays. That's why posted an answer.

Comment: How does `np.insert(a, a.shape[-1], 1, axis=-1)` compare, speed-wise?

Comment: @PM2Ring I would think it would be slower than the posted ones, a guesstimate tho.

Answer (score 2):

The alternative to Divakar's suggestion would be `np.dstack`:

```
np.dstack((a, np.ones(a.shape[:-1] + (1, ))))

array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]],
```

```
a = np.zeros((800,300,400))

%timeit np.dstack((a, np.ones(a.shape[:-1] + (1, ))))
1 loop, best of 3: 433 ms per loop
```

Comment: Code for `dstack`: `concatenate([atleast_3d(_m) for _m in tup], 2)`

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily and elegantly using `np.append()`.  Example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((8,3,4))
a = np.append(a,np.ones((8,3,1)),axis=2)
```

In fact, if you want the general method:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((b,c,4))
a = np.append(a,np.ones((b,c,1)),axis=2)
```

If you want number C instead of 1, you can multiply np.ones() with that number C. 
Hope this helps!

Comment: True but i would suggest `np.concatenate` since `np.append` calls `concatenate` and you could avoid some intermediate declarations

Comment: Yes, I think you are right that `np.concatenate` is faster for this purpose, but perhaps if you want something else then only ones, `np.append` would be faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.pad`:

```
width = ((0,0),(0,0),(0,1))
np.pad(a, width, 'constant', constant_values=1.)
```